# How to evaluate is_empty for 2-tuple lists in Lambda calculus?

Tags: reductions, lambda-calculus, evaluation-strategies

This question has been handled various ways, but let me show my case.

I want to find out, if the given list is empty with these constraints:

```
TRUE = (L a b . a)
FALSE = (L a b . b)
NIL = FALSE    
ZERO = FALSE
ONE = (L x y . (x y))
TWO = (L x y . (x (x y)))

PAIR = (L a b s . (s a b))

EMPTY = (PAIR NIL NIL)
EMPTY? = (L l . (l FALSE TRUE))
```

a. `(EMPTY? EMPTY)` should give `TRUE`.

b. `(EMPTY? (PAIR ZERO (PAIR ONE (PAIR TWO EMPTY))))` should give `FALSE`.

I've seen different versions for `EMPTY?` like `(L l . (l (L _ , FALSE) TRUE))` and such, but none of them gives me correct resolution.

So I'd like to know, if there is something on the above definitions, that does not work. Also, to verify that one strategy works, I'd like to see reduction steps for finding out correct answers for a. and b. starting from these expanded forms:

a. `(L l . (l (L a b . b) (L a b . a)) (L a b s . (s a b) (L a b . b) (L a b . b)))`

b. `(L l . (l (L a b . b) (L a b . a)) (L a b s . (s a b) (L a b . b) (L a b s . (s a b) (L x y . (x y)) (L a b s . (s a b) (L x y . (x (x y))) (L a b s . (s a b) (L a b . b) (L a b . b))))))`

Comment: There are various ways to encode lists/pairs in Lambda calc. Please give a ref for which you're using. You seem to have muddled together different ways. Going by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Pairs, your definition of NIL is wrong. Going by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#List_encodings (which is not the usual approach), your definition of NIL is wrong. The definition for EMPTY? must rely on what definition you are using for NIL.